# How secure is root read-permissions?

Tags: permissions, security

How secure is a file whos permissions are set so only root has any privileges with the file? Say I had the file on an unencrypted ext4 partition, would I be able to boot up another live OS, copy the file off of the partition, and read it?

My question is, can another OS copy a root file off a partition, and is there any limitation to what that other OS can do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File permissions are only a hindrance for restricted users of the currently running OS.

Anyone with physical access to the computer can circumvent them, simply by booting a Live-CD and gaining root privileges in that live session.

Comment: That's what I thought, just wanted to confirm it. Thanks!